# While statement inside .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code.

```
    document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = "<table>" +
    while (c<b) {  

    c++;
    } + "</table>"
```

What I want the while statement to do is to create the rows for the table (the "" stuff).

Is it possible with my approach or should I try another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` statements don't resolve to a value, you cannot just drop them in the middle of an expression.

Consider the following:

```
document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = "<table>";

while (c<b) {  
  document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML += c++;
}

document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML += "</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is a statement, not an expression. **You can put expressions inside statements, and you can put expressions inside other expressions, but you can't put a statement inside an expression.**

You could, however, use an array to store the results of whatever you're doing in the loop, and then join it together at the end, like this:

```
var result = [],
    r;
while (c < b) {
    r = /* do something */;
    result.push(r);
    c++;
}
document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = "<table>" + result.join('') + "</table>";
```

`result.join('')` is an expression, so it fits into what you were trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
    var html = '<table>';
    // make sure b and c are initialized somehow
    while(c < b)
    {
        // start new row
        html+= '<tr>';
        // add cells
        html+= '<td>' + 'a cell' + '</td>';
        html+= '<td>' + 'another cell' + '</td>';
        // end row
        html+= '</tr>';

        // iterate your looping variable so you aren't infinite
        c++;
    }
    // end table
    html+= '</table>';
    $('#stage').html(html);
```

Each time through the while adds a new row of data to the table.

It is generally better to create a string variable with all of the html in it and then add it all at once to the DOM.  This is much faster because you only manipulate the DOM once rather than several times.